# Google Webmasters main site version https://non-www but receiving "phantom" results with http://www version

Tags: https, joomla, redirect, http-redirect, google-search-console

We have recently transitioned back to Bluehost from GoDaddy, and since the transition, our search engine rankings have been negatively affected...

When logged onto Google with my webmaster credentials and searching for results using the main key word relating to our site, I receive the following dialog and surprised to discover two site version options to select from when there should only be one, the https non-www main version of the site (http is redirected).

[https non www view (our main site)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDmST.png)

The site with http no longer appears in google search results, however upon selecting the http www view, I am presented with results that show that this version is supposedly receiving nearly three times the amount of impressions to mention the performance of an average position of #1 e (don’t I wish).

[This is the http with www view that no longer appears in search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gqVx.png)

The versions of our site added to google webmasters are as follows

1. http www
2. http non-www
3. https www
4. https non-www

http www is redirected to http non-www on our site. Our choice of CMS platforms is Joomla, which uses a force SSL feature to automatically redirect all http traffic to https.

The following is the script in the .htaccess file to redirect http www to non-www:

RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.xn-----zldghbe3agy5a4ai0fk2a.com  [NC]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://xn-----zldghbe3agy5a4ai0fk2a.com/$1 [r=301,L]

and the other day, I added the following lines into the .htacess file:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

Is there anything else required to assure that all site versions are redirected correctly to the https non www version of our site?

[This is a link to our website - its main language is Hebrew](https://xn-----zldghbe3agy5a4ai0fk2a.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a better fit for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually also a good fit for the Joomla stack exchange [joomla.se.]